# How to sort an ArrayList which contain more than 1000 different Strings on the basis of similairy to another given String

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, similarity

I have an ArrayList which contains some 1000 strings. I want to sort this list on the basis of similarity to given String from outside. The Strings which are very close to the String will come in the top.

For eg. I have a String like "Beauty and The Beast".

My Arraylist contains String like:

RedWall
Beauty and the Beast 3
BlueWall
BeautyQueen I
Beast of Rome  II
Beauty and the Beast 1
Beast with The Beauty
BlueWall 2
BeautyQueen II
Beast of Rome  I
Beauty and the Beast 2
...

So After sorting this arraylist, it should be something like..

Beauty and the Beast 1
Beauty and the Beast 2
Beauty and the Beast 3
Beast with The Beauty
BeautyQueen I
BeautyQueen II
Beast of Rome I
Beast of Rome II
BlueWall
BlueWall 2
RedWall

Some thing like this.. I dont know how the order is going to be after Beauty and the Beast 3.. 
But it should pick the String which have exactly same String to be in the beginning.

I am looking for some algorithm which can actually help me in implementing this task in Java.

I have also heard about using Levenstein Distance, but I have no idea on how this can be used for my task.

Any pointers will be a lot of help.

Comment: all you have to do is to play with your custom `Comparator<String>`

Comment: Ya.. I agree, but it should have some good logic in doing that. I am looking for ideas in that logic.

Comment: Try a radix tree for forcing the exact matches, morpheus05 answer seems to cover the rest..

Comment: @Sen you wanted pointers.. i gave you the pointers.. :-)  R u looking for the code?

Comment: @sanbhat I know I need to use my own comparator, but i need some pseudo code or atleast an idea of which algorithm to use.. Thats why we come to stack overflow..

Answer (score 2):

Sort according to the levenstein distance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.  With this distance you can define how close strings are to each other. Implement this in a comparator.

Here is a implementation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Take the code from sanbhat and replace his score function with the levenstein distance from the wikipedia I posted.

The idea is, that you compare each string with your base string and check, if the distances are smaller or greater. A visuell example: Imagine a 2d plane with a point called x. Now you have a list of points and want to sort them according to their distance to x. What you do is, you compare two points a and b from the list by calculating the distance from a and b to x. If a has the smaller distance to x then a must be smaller then b.

Hth

Answer (score 2):

I have created a custom comparator as per your need and here's the code

- `s` is the search string, all the matching/closely matching string to the `s` should appear first
- I have created a `Set<String> matches` to store all the tokens(words) of the search string
- I have created a comparator `c` which has a method `getScore(String)`, which basically gives a **score** as per *number of matches* found in the given string of the list against the *search string*
- If the `getScore` method returns `0` for both the strings of list OR if both the strings have **same number of matches**, I am sorting them in their **natural ordering**.
- else I am **promoting** the string which has highest match by returning -ve

  ```
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  l.add("RedWall");
  l.add("Beauty and the Beast 3");
  l.add("BlueWall");
  l.add("BeautyQueen I");
  l.add("Beast of Rome II");
  l.add("Beauty and the Beast 1");
  l.add("Beast with The Beauty");
  l.add("BlueWall 2");
  l.add("BeautyQueen II");
  l.add("Beast of Rome I");
  l.add("Beauty and the Beast 2");

  String s = "Beauty and the Beast"; //search string
  final Set<String> matches = new HashSet<String>();
  for(String tokens : s.split("\\s")) {
      matches.add(tokens.toLowerCase()); //convert the search string into tokens
  }

  Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
          int scoreDiff = getScore(o1) - getScore(o2);
          if((getScore(o1) == 0 && getScore(o2) == 0) || scoreDiff == 0) {
              return o1.compareTo(o2);
          }
          return - (getScore(o1) - getScore(o2));
      }

      private int getScore(String s) {
          int score = 0;
          for(String match : matches) {
              if(s.toLowerCase().contains(match)) {
                  score++;
              }
          }
          return score;
      }
  };
  Collections.sort(l, c);
  for(String ss : l) {
      System.out.println(ss);
  }
  ```

and here's the output

```
Beauty and the Beast 1
Beauty and the Beast 2
Beauty and the Beast 3
Beast with The Beauty
Beast of Rome I
Beast of Rome II
BeautyQueen I
BeautyQueen II
BlueWall
BlueWall 2
RedWall
```

Comment: Thanks Sambat for the answer. Lemme try to see, how I can modify this to suite my needs. Just one question, why dint you go for LevenshteinDistance algorithm.

Comment: @Sen I am yet to read about that algorithm and I thought playing with comparator will be good option. As we know the contract for `compareTo(o1,o2)` method, we should achieve what we need by returning appropriate integers